# Remove specific character strings from text file using sed, no change to output file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, bioinformatics

Edit: added block quote text

I have a tab delimited text file (`acc.paired.txt`) of illumina sample names (`head`):

```
SRR10598163_R1.fastq.gz  SRR8916417_R2.fastq.gz
SRR10598049_R1.fastq.gz  SRR10598163_R2.fastq.gz  SRR8916418_R1.fastq.gz
SRR10598049_R2.fastq.gz  SRR10598164_R1.fastq.gz  SRR8916418_R2.fastq.gz
SRR10598050_R1.fastq.gz  SRR10598164_R2.fastq.gz  SRR8916419_R1.fastq.gz
SRR10598050_R2.fastq.gz  SRR10598165_R1.fastq.gz  SRR8916419_R2.fastq.gz
SRR10598051_R1.fastq.gz  SRR10598165_R2.fastq.gz  SRR8916420_R1.fastq.gz
SRR10598051_R2.fastq.gz  SRR10598166_R1.fastq.gz  SRR8916420_R2.fastq.gz
SRR10598052_R1.fastq.gz  SRR10598166_R2.fastq.gz  SRR8916421_R1.fastq.gz
SRR10598052_R2.fastq.gz  SRR10598167_R1.fastq.gz  SRR8916421_R2.fastq.gz
SRR10598053_R1.fastq.gz  SRR10598167_R2.fastq.gz  SRR8916422_R1.fastq.gz
SRR10598053_R2.fastq.gz  SRR10598168_R1.fastq.gz  SRR8916422_R2.fastq.gz
SRR10598054_R1.fastq.gz  SRR10598168_R2.fastq.gz  SRR8916423_R1.fastq.gz
```

and I'd like to make two changes, 1) remove duplicate sample names and 2) remove all characters after the specific sample name. My goal output is a tab delimited text file which contains just the `SRR###` numbers (no `_R#.fastq.qz`) with no duplicates. Example goal output:

```
SRR10598163
SRR8916417
SRR10598049
SRR8916418
SRR10598164
SRR10598050
SRR8916419
SRR10598165
SRR10598051
SRR8916420
SRR10598166
SRR10598052
SRR8916421
SRR10598167
SRR10598053
SRR8916422
SRR10598054
SRR10598168
SRR8916423
```

I turned to `sed` to remove character patterns:

```
`sed 's| _R1.fastq.gz||g' acc.paired.txt > out.txt`
```

But `out.txt` had no changes.

TIA.

Comment: Please do not post images of text, but the text itself.  It is much easier to work with that.  Looks like you have unwanted whitespace in your sed-statement.

Comment: I made the edits as requested, thank you @ilkkachu and markgraf.  Also, my text file was constructed by navigating into the directory containing the zipped files and using `dir > acc.paired.txt`

Comment: You got your solution, but if you still like to know why your `sed` command failed: You seem to have a whitespace before the `_R`, so it will not match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `grep` and `sort`:

```
grep -oE '\bSR[^_]+' file | sort -u
```

```
SRR10598049
SRR10598050
SRR10598051
[...]
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `\b` | the boundary anchor between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char anchor |
| `SR` | 'SR' |
| `[^_]+` | any character except: `_` (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

Answer (score 4):

Using GNU awk for multi-char `RS` plus `\s` and `\S` shorthand for `[[:space:]]` and `[^[:space:]]`:

```
$ awk -v RS='_\\S+\\s*' '!seen[$0]++' file
SRR10598163
SRR8916417
SRR10598049
SRR8916418
SRR10598164
SRR10598050
SRR8916419
SRR10598165
SRR10598051
SRR8916420
SRR10598166
SRR10598052
SRR8916421
SRR10598167
SRR10598053
SRR8916422
SRR10598168
SRR10598054
SRR8916423
```

Answer (score 2):

GNU **sed** command would be like this:

```
sed 's/\s/\n/g;s/_R[0-9].fastq.gz//g' acc.paired.txt | sort |uniq > out.txt
```

you can also do it with **awk**:

```
awk '{gsub("_R[0-9].fastq.gz","\n", $0)gsub("\n ","\n",$0);gsub("\n$","",$0);print}' acc.paired.txt | sort | uniq > out.txt
```

the second and third gsub functions are used to remove whitespaces and the last newline

Comment: FYI `sort | uniq` = `sort -u`.

Answer (score 1):

You could

- change all spaces to newlines with `tr`
- remove everything that matches `_R1.fastq.gz` with `sed`
- remove empty lines with `grep`
- and sort the output, removing duplicates with `sort`:

```
% < acc.paired.txt tr ' ' '\n'  | sed -e 's/_R.\.fastq\.gz//' | grep . | sort -u
SRR10598049
SRR10598050
SRR10598051
SRR10598052
[...]
```

Apart from the ordering, the output is the same as shown in your question.

Of course in regexes, `.` matches any character, and a literal dot is matched with `\.`. `grep .` works to keep only lines that contain at least one character, so losing the empty lines the `tr` created from back-to-back spaces. This also assumes there's just `R1`, to `R9` there, not `R11` or so.